# sqlite3_reset() when is it needed?

Tags: c, sqlite

Before you tell me to read the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html), yes I have read them. But my own tests tell me I can sometimes call repeatedly `sqlite3_step()` on some prepared statements without resetting them first. Examples are: `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`. Can you shed some light on when I need to reset a prepared statement, as I would like to avoid making the call whenever possible?

EDIT: The docs say (my bold):

> The life-cycle of a prepared statement object **usually** goes like this:

Comment: Just because it *appears* to work without calling `reset()` every time, doesn't mean that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the sqlite sources:

```
/* We used to require that sqlite3_reset() be called before retrying
** sqlite3_step() after any error or after SQLITE_DONE.  But beginning
** with version 3.7.0, we changed this so that sqlite3_reset() would
** be called automatically instead of throwing the SQLITE_MISUSE error.
** This "automatic-reset" change is not technically an incompatibility, 
** since any application that receives an SQLITE_MISUSE is broken by
** definition.
**
** Nevertheless, some published applications that were originally written
** for version 3.6.23 or earlier do in fact depend on SQLITE_MISUSE 
** returns, and those were broken by the automatic-reset change.  As a
** a work-around, the SQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET compile-time restores the
** legacy behavior of returning SQLITE_MISUSE for cases where the 
** previous sqlite3_step() returned something other than a SQLITE_LOCKED
** or SQLITE_BUSY error.
*/
```

So with version 3.7.0 sqlite_reset is not needed if you reach SQLITE_DONE and want to step through again.

You need to call sqlite3_finalize to free the statement when you are done with it.see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html

Comment: There is a problem with this answer. I find, for example, I need to reset even `INSERT` prepared statements and I'm not interested in stepping through the results at all, just in `SQLITE_DONE` result.

Comment: Just because this is an error that SQLite can automatically recover from does not imply that it does not remain an error.

Comment: No, please read again, It is not an error now, because it is an API change.

Comment: @frast It is not true. I find my prepared INSERT and REMOVE statements did not autoreset. Failed to function without a reset, no error was returned.

Comment: @user1095108 are you sure you are using version 3.7.0 or higher?

Comment: @user1095108 you are right. It is only true for sqlite3_step

Comment: @frast could you be more clear in what I was right? Could you update your answer, if I was right? I am using version 3.10.0.

Comment: @user1095108 may be you forgot to reset the bindings? If you execute your insert/remove using sqlite3_step() it should work without calling reset. What error code do you get?

Comment: @frast That's the point. No error code, but the INSERT, REMOVE simply doesn't do what it should.

Comment: @user1095108 this is strange. Do you commit your transaction or close your db before you open it to see if it was changed?

Comment: @frast Yes, this is just one strange issue. For example, if I bind a finished prepared statement and the reset, it won't work, even though a reset should not affect the bindings. People are using sqlite like a flock of sheep according to the reset recipe and some bugs simply don't surface because of that, in my opinion.

Comment: @user1095108 we are using sqlite quite a bit here and never had problems. Think a bit about your usage pattern or your wrapper if you use one. There must be something else wrong because the library is proved to work properly.

Comment: @frast Yes, but there are no saintly library without bugs. It is a good library to be sure, but not without bugs. Check out my wrapper, maybe: https://github.com/janezz55/sqliteutils.git

Comment: @user1095108 nice work. Some calls need error checks (reset, bind). If you use your library and step returned an error you need to reset the statement before using it again, Else I think your API wrapper is going to be great. May be you should think about throwing exceptions instead of returning error codes. But this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @frast I have strict performance requirements. This means I expect the user to check (assert) the return value. The assert will be compiled away in release mode. The binds need to be fast, so there are no checks there. If the binds are unsuccessful, the user will probably see for himself. The problem with binds is. If I bind/reset/step the prepared statement won't work, but if I reset/bind/step it will execute OK.

Comment: I think this can only happen if the previous statement failed. Then you have to call reset before bind again.

Comment: Even if performance matters, I think correctness trumps performance. You should at least consider to fail-fast in case of unexpected errors.

Answer (score 2):

One more issue with not resetting statement, that I stumbled upon, is that DB may remain locked until the prepared statement is reset. E.g. sqlite3_wal_checkpoint() would return SQL_LOCKED.